LangChain with Llama3 Stuck at Entering new AgentExecutor chain
I am trying to run a Pandas dataframe agent using ollama and llama3 but I am stuck at Entering new AgentExectur chain... . The ollama task is also continuously utilizing higher resources once the chain is entered.
llm=Ollama(model="llama3")

# Initializing the agent 
agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(llm=llm, 
              df=df, 
              verbose=True,
              agent_type=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
              include_df_in_prompt=True,

                )


where is llama3? you can provide more information?

don't know if you already got it to work.  I was testing around and found that it needs to have an API to talk to.  At the end you can install Ollama and in Ollama you could download a GGUF model or use one already provided by Ollama.
Here is my snippet:
from langchain_community.llms import Ollama
from langchain_experimental.agents.agent_toolkits.pandas.base import create_pandas_dataframe_agent

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
llm = Ollama(model='llama3')
agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(llm = llm, df = df, verbose = True)
text = 'How many rows are there?'
result = agent.invoke(text)

Hope it works for you.
